# How can a service account authenticate in gcloud without changing the default gcloud account in the environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I use `gcloud  auth activate-service-account ...` to login a service account to `gcloud` in a script. When the script is done, `gcloud` remains logged into that service account.

I prefer that `gcloud` remain logged in with my normal user account, so I can use it interactively.

How can I authenticate with a service account temporarily -- just within a single script execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant the [Service Account Token Creator role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#token-creator-role) to the "normal user account" and take advantage of the [`--impersonate-service-account = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL` flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--impersonate-service-account) for the gcloud commands you need to run within your script to avoid using the `gcloud  auth activate-service-account ...` within your script at all or simply add the [`gcloud config set account ACCOUNT` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#account) at the end of your script in order to make sure that the normal user account is set after the script is done.

Comment: Thank you. Your second approach did it for me